# Margin auto not working when centering a div inside another div

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to center a `div` horizontally inside another `div`. Here's my html:

```css
.block {
  padding: 0px 20px;
  max-width: 820px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ff0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="container">
    <button>£10</button>
    <button>£20</button>
    <button>£30</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I want the red `div` centered inside the yellow `div`. At the moment it is aligned left.

Here's the codepen:
https://codepen.io/carlrippon/pen/MWwaORv?editors=1111

I don't need to support old versions of IE - just IE11

Comment: for working `margin: 0 autho;` the div that you set style `margin: 0 auto;` It should not cover the whole space, so must set width for it like `max-width: 80%;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your red DIV (`.container`) is an inline-block, that's why `margin: 0 auto` won't work.

Just add `text-align: center;` to its parent (`.block`)

```css
.block {
  padding: 0px 20px;
  max-width: 820px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ff0;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block; 
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
 <div class="container">
   <button>£10</button>
   <button>£20</button>
   <button>£30</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```css
.block {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  max-width: 820px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ff0;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block; 
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
 <div class="container">
   <button>£10</button>
   <button>£20</button>
   <button>£30</button>
  </div>
</div>
```